# How do I access specific items in an object of arrays in reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to toggle an item's completed property by with clicking. The problem is I have no idea how to do this within reducer state. The property is stored inside an object of arrays which makes it tricky to locate in reducer.

App.js

```
import React,{ useReducer,useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {reducer, initialState} from "./reducers/reducer"

function App() {
  const [item,setItem] = useState("")
  const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
const handleCompleted = () => {
  dispatch({type:"TOGGLE_COMPLETED",payload:0})
  console.log(state[0])
}
const handleChanges = e => {
  setItem(e.target.value)
}
const addTodo = e => {
  dispatch({type:"ADD_TODO",newItem:{item:item,id:Date.now(),completed:false}})
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(state)
}
  return (
    <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
      <button>submitTodo</button>
      <input onChange={handleChanges} value={item} />
      <div>
      <button onClick={handleCompleted}>completed</button>
      {state.list.map(i => <p key ={i.id}>{i.item}</p>)}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {

        list :[{item: 'Learn about reducers',
        completed: false,
        id: 3892987589}]
}




export const reducer = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "TOGGLE_COMPLETED" : 
        return state.list[action.payload].completed = !state.list[action.payload].completed

        case "ADD_TODO" : 
        return {...state,list:[...state.list,action.newItem]}


        default:
            return state}

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function as follows in your App.js

```
const handleCompleted = (id) => {
  dispatch({type:"TOGGLE_COMPLETED",payload:id})
}
```

In the render function 
change `<button onClick={handleCompleted}>completed</button>` to

```
{state.list.map(i => <p key ={i.id}>{i.item}<button onClick={this.handleCompleted.bind(this, i,id)}>completed</button></p>)}<button onClick={this.handleCompleted.bind(this, id)}>completed</button>
```

And in Reducers.js

**Note: Usually, you would create a map of ids corresponding to the items for ease of updates. But this would also work for now.**

```
export const reducer = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "TOGGLE_COMPLETED" : 
        const modifiedState = state.map(item=> {
          if(item.id === action.payload.id){
            return {
              ...item,
              completed: true
            }
          }
          return item
        });
        return modifiedState

        case "ADD_TODO" : 
        return {...state,list:[...state.list,action.newItem]}


        default:
            return state}

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). In your case use the `id` to find the index in the array then change the status of `completed`

```js
const initialState = {

  list: [{
    item: 'Learn about reducers',
    completed: false,
    id: 3892987589
  }]
}



function changeStatus(id) {
  let getIndex = initialState.list.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
  initialState.list[getIndex].completed = true;
}

changeStatus(3892987589);
console.log(initialState.list)
```